# Selecting Random Variables in Action Script

Tags: variables, actionscript, random

Is it possible to randomly select from variables in action script?

I have tried using or -

question.text = question1 || question.text = question2;

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a random variable, use an array:

```
var x:int = 5;
var y:int = 1;
var z:int = "string";
var w:int = "bla";

var randomSelector:Array = [x, y, z, w];
var random:* = randomSelector[Math.floor(randomSelector.length * Math.random())];

// random is now a random variable from either x, y, z, or w
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the options into an array, and randomly selecting an index from that array.

```
var options:Array = ["Hello", "World", "I'm", "alive"];
var randomlySelectedOption:String = options[Math.floor(options.length * Math.random())]
```